# iOS: Best practices for a "one-way" navigation controller?

Tags: ios, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm developing an app which is essentially a sequence of many different tests (for simplicity, think about an SAT test or a Mensa test). Each test is implemented in a different View+View Controller.

Initially I wanted to use Storyboards and UINavigationControllers for managing the sequence of the tests and the transitions between them, but now I'm questioning the validity of this approach. A UINavigationController is a stack while my navigation is one-way only (once you've completed a test you can't go back). Is there a better way to implement the app? Can I still leverage Storyboards somehow?

Comment: Even if you opt to not use a NavigationController, and you go with a storyboard, you're going to need to push ViewControllers with segues. Doing this manually would be no different than using a Navigation Controller with the backButton disabled. I don't see the advantage in avoiding a NavigationController here.

Comment: @jhilgert00 why is he "going to need to push ViewControllers with segues"? Using containment, that's not necessary. As to the advantage, I assume it's because if you have lots of scenes, there's no benefit to pushing them onto a stack if you don't need them. Just takes up memory.

Comment: Having said that (and having demonstrated how to do it), I personally would not be inclined to have a different scenes for each question. I'd have a single scene, store my questions in such a way that I could use the single scene to render all of the questions, or a scene for each "type" of question. HTML would be one format. Another method would be to have a database or plist with the questions, maybe with fields like "title", "question", "image", and the answer(s). When doing an app like this, the questions should be in the app's model, not in the code/storyboard.

Comment: @Rob, thanks a lot for your excellent answer (I'm going to research it a little further but it looks like I'll accept it). As per your comment, tests are not simple questions, they are mostly activity based or puzzles, so HTML is not really an option (better, I guess one could implement some if not all of them in HTML5, but why?)

Comment: @Wolfy I was assuming that the questions were going to consist of a question, an image, some additional text, and then a list of possible answers. If there's some pattern like that, then some data-driven approach with a single view controller would make sense. But if each of the questions requires radically different UI (e.g. the user is going to be moving things around, etc.), then perhaps that doesn't make sense and something like I outlined below makes sense. But if there is some pattern to the questions, then not having to write a separate controller for each question might make sense.

Comment: @Rob, very nice solution. This is exactly why I didn't post my response as an answer. Upvote :)

Comment: @Wolfy And, by the way, a `UIPageViewController` is yet another option to consider if my containment approach below doesn't make sense. I always view custom containers as a last ditch effort. As Apple advises, one should only use custom containment when none of the standard controllers can do the job. But I wasn't trying to suggest that you do a HTML5 app. Only that, if possible, you might minimize controllers using some data-driven approach if there is a pattern to the question formats.

Comment: @Rob, yes I understand your point and I agree, sorry if my OP was not clear enough.

Comment: @Rob: "As Apple advises, one should only use custom containment when none of the standard controllers can do the job." That's exactly why I wanted to use a `UINavigationController` in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use a custom container view controller. So to your main scene, add a "container view". If your target is iOS6, then when editing your storyboard there is a special "container view" object that you can now drag onto your custom container view controller's scene:

[image: container view]

If iOS 5, then (a) you have to create the first child scene manually; (b) give it a unique storyboard id (in my example, `InitialChild`, and (c) you manually instantiate that first child controller and add it as a child programmatically. Thus, assuming you have a `UIView` called `containerView` in your custom container view controller's scene, you can have a method like:

```
- (void)addInitialChild
{
    UIViewController *child = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialChild"];

    [self addChildViewController:child];
    child.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    [self.containerView addSubview:child.view];
    [child didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

When you want to transition to the next scene, subclass your own `UIStoryboardSegue`:

In ReplaceSegue.h:

```
@interface ReplaceSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

In ReplaceSegue.m

```
@implementation ReplaceSegue

- (void)perform
{
    UIViewController *source = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destination = self.destinationViewController;
    UIViewController *container = source.parentViewController;

    [container addChildViewController:destination];
    destination.view.frame = source.view.frame;
    [source willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    [container transitionFromViewController:source
                           toViewController:destination
                                   duration:0.5
                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                 animations:^{
                                 }
                                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                     [source removeFromParentViewController];
                                     [destination didMoveToParentViewController:container];
                                 }];
}
@end
```

Then, when doing a segue from the first contained scene to the next, specify a "custom" segue, and use this "ReplaceSegue" as the class (just click on the segue to select it and then look at the "Attributes inspector").

[image]

The resulting storyboard might look like (note the "`{}`" designation between the various children):

[image: containment storyboard]

---

References:

- For general discussion of containment, see [Implementing a View Container Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) in the *UIViewController Class Reference*.
- For some details about the implementation, see [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) in the *View Controller Programming Guide for iOS.*

Comment: excellent answer, I think I've got the gist of it but I still have one doubt: I can't have Interface Builder to set the rootViewController relationship with the first child. How can you do that?

Comment: @Wolfy If you want to add the container to your first scene, when editing a storyboard, if you open the "object library" (you can press control-option-command-3), you'll see a "container view" in that list which you can drag onto your scene.

Comment: oops, you had that in your answer, my bad!

Comment: btw, it's worth noting that the Embed Segue required for the Container View is for iOS 6 only. Everything else should work with iOS 5.

Comment: @Wolfy Quite right. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Then just load the next view controller and replace current view (in some top-level view or in  app window) with the new one. Add animations if you want. What's the problem?

Comment: Storyboards are very convenient to lay out the tests and to rearrange the sequence if necessary. That's the main reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use view animation to avoid push viewcontrollers.you can give view animation like pushing a VC