# Change child view controller

Tags: ios, view, controller, parent-child

I have a view controller that when I press a button a child view controller appear. This works perfectly but I want to change this child view controller for other one if I press the button next that is inside of this to do like two step login.
Any idea? Because from the main view controller I know how show a child but from the child I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Assuming we're talking about custom container view controllers here, you can have the child invoke a method back to the parent to perform the transition. Or you can do a custom segue that replaces a child controller: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125145/ios-best-practices-for-a-one-way-navigation-controller/14125580#14125580

Comment: Thank you for you answer. So I have to back to the parent and show the other view controller as a child. But how know that I want to show the other one. Because I try to replace the child like segue but the new view controller appeared in all window not like the first one.

Comment: Ok, finally I get the custom segue that replaces a child. :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If using storyboards, you can create your own child replace segue, e.g.:

ReplaceSegue.h

```
@interface ReplaceSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

ReplaceSegue.m

```
@implementation ReplaceSegue

- (void)perform
{
    UIViewController *source = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destination = self.destinationViewController;
    UIViewController *container = source.parentViewController;

    [container addChildViewController:destination];
    destination.view.frame = source.view.frame;
    [source willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    [container transitionFromViewController:source
                           toViewController:destination
                                   duration:0.5
                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                 animations:^{
                                 }
                                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                     [source removeFromParentViewController];
                                     [destination didMoveToParentViewController:container];
                                 }];
}

@end
```

You can then open your storyboard, put a container view on your container view controller and on the child controller, put a custom segue from the first child scene to the second child scene. You'll want to specify the `ReplaceSegue` class for the custom segue between the two child scenes:

[image: container controller storyboard]

Note that if you've properly used autolayout or autosizing on the second child view, everything will work fine (especially with the manual setting of the frame of the destination controller's view in the `ReplaceSegue`). But in Interface Builder, the layout of that second child scene doesn't look quite right and can make the proper design of the scene a little awkward, because (as of Xcode 4.5, at least) the "Simulated Metrics" for the second child scene doesn't do a good job inferring the the proper size. So you should probably change that second child scene's simulated metrics' size from "Inferred" to "Freeform" and then manually adjust the size of the second child scene:

[image: container storyboard with manually adjusted second child scene size]

It's not very elegant Xcode experience, but it works. And if you're properly using autolayout or autosizing masks, minor variations are handled very gracefully.

Comment: Note that it should be possible to add a dummy "push" segue between Child View 1 and Child View 2 in order to force Xcode to properly infer the metrics

Comment: Hey @Rob: Thank you VERY MUCH! I've been following two tutorials and the Apple Documentation to make this Simple Transition and your Answer just Helped me solve this Navigation Issue in a few Minutes... So What if its not that Elegant? It's BRILLIANT :-)

Comment: YOU NEED MORE UPVOTES!

Comment: What if you need to swap back to the first one... Is there an elegant way to handle that?

Comment: @tybro0103 Just have another replace segue from the second child to the first child. Generally circular segue references are really bad idea (because standard push/present segues keep stack of all of the prior segues, and you'll end up with a ton of abandoned view controllers sitting in memory), but in this case it's ok because the particular implementation of the above `ReplaceSegue` will release the prior one, eliminating this memory issue.

Comment: @Rob But if there's more than 2?

Comment: @tybro0103 Just have segues between the various children that you're segueing to-and-from. If it's just from A to B to C and back to A, that's pretty simple. If you have a dozen and you want to be able to transition from one to any other one, then you might want to do this programmatically, as putting all of those segues in a storyboard will be a mess.

Comment: I ended up doing this but put the segue from the parent to the child. It works well, but requires some rather hackish code to determine which child to transition from.

Comment: If you put segues from each child to each other child that would quickly become unmanageable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61582/discussion-between-rob-and-tybro0103).