# View does not display after pushViewController

Tags: ios6, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

My storyboard has the following layout

> ```
>                                          MyView1ViewController (root controller)
>                                         /
> ```
>
> ContainerView -->  MyNavigationController ---------
>
> ```
>                                        \
>                                         MyView2ViewController
> ```

A container view embeds a UINavigationController which has MyView1ViewController as the root view controller. I created a manual push segue to MyView2ViewController from the UINavigationController.

Based on user input, View1 or View2 is displayed. In this sample the button just toggles between the two controllers. If View1 (root controller) is displayed then push the View2 controller. The controller gets pushed onto the stack but View2 never displays. The code listed below shows how I implemented this:

```
- (void)transitionToView:(int)type {

if (self.v2Controller == nil) {
    self.v2Controller = (MyView2ViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"];
}

NSLog(@"top=%@", self.topViewController);
NSLog(@"visible=%@", self.visibleViewController);
for (id cntrllr in self.viewControllers) {
    NSLog(@"children=%@", cntrllr);
}

switch (type) {
    case 2:
        **[self pushViewController:self.v2Controller animated:YES];**
        break;
        
    case 1:
        [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        break;
        
    default:
        [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        break;
}
for (id cntrllr in self.viewControllers) {
    NSLog(@"after children=%@", cntrllr);
}
NSLog(@"after visible=%@", self.visibleViewController);
```

}

Here are the log messages when I run in the simulator and run this code:

top=MyView1ViewController: 0x7425f80

visible=MyView1ViewController: 0x7425f80

children=MyView1ViewController: 0x7425f80

after children=MyView1ViewController: 0x7425f80

after children=MyView2ViewController: 0x10a142c0

after visible=MyView2ViewController: 0x10a142c0

My interpretation is that I am pushing the View2 controller onto the navigation stack and it **should** be the visible controller but View2 is not being displayed.

I have looked at issues with similar titles but nothing seems to apply to my situation. Is there a problem with my configuration? Is there something I am missing in IB? Should I expect the controller to display its view simply by doing a push? Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: So my problem is my lack of understanding of the view hierarchy. I came up with a solution that does not use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. I need to see some code samples to see how this was meant to be used.

Comment: The right answer is to define a custom seque as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158960/change-child-view-controller?lq=1). This will replace my mis-guided attempt to use a navigation controller.