# Container View replace segue in Storyboard: New size too big

Tags: ios, containers, segue

I'm trying to replace a child view controller via a push segue in storyboard. With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158960/change-child-view-controller) code I got it almost working

Well now I only have the problem that my new view is bigger than the first child view. So I of course want it embedded in the container so the user can scroll down within the container and that the container doesn't overlap my footer. Where do I need to change that?

[image: Storyboard setup]
[image: Initial (first) child view controller, correctly displayed]
[image: Too big child view]

Comment: Please put the code in the post. Linked code has a tendency of going missing.

Comment: You should set the frame of the new controller's view to the container view's bounds.

Comment: And how would I do that? And why do I need to do that? I tought since the view is in the container it is automatically not bigger than the container...