# Embed segue - switching initial UIViewController and the contained UIViewController dynamically

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

What I need to do is basically build a container(view controller) that can change its child view controller dynamically and also set it's initial view controller dynamically.

I never used the Embed segue before so I thought I'll give it a shot.
However, using it seems to allow me to change the child view controller dynamically using a custom segue between the children view controllers but the initial view controllers seem to be fixed to the one I dragged the segue to in the StoryBoard(The custom segue here would be something [alone these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158960/change-child-view-controller)).

I know I can achieve what i'm looking for by creating x custom segue (where x is the number of children VCs I need) from the container view controller directly to the children and just calling these segues in code based on my needs.
But if that's the only way, what's the reason for using the "Embed" segue, is it only for really simple scenario's ?

Answer (score 0):

An embed segue is not just for really simple scenarii. It can get pretty complicated. A major purpose is to cleanly separate code related to different concerns, that may still coexist on the same screen, into different view controllers. For instance, you could have an authentication controller and a preferences controller, both embedded into a single profile controller.