# Unwind Segue + Swipe Gesture Recognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have a swipe gesture recognizer that allows me to transition from VC to VC.  As of recent I have been simply using Modal Segue to go from VC to VC. Upon learning that this was increasing memory usage and creating a new instance everytime I swiped my research led me to the Unwind technique.  My question how do I implement the swipe gesture recognizer control and the unwind technique?

I have seen it done with buttons but I am not sure if it can be down with swipe gesture?

Comment: There's no difference between using a gesture recognizer and using a button. Just connect the IBAction to the gesture recognizer in IB or set the action method in code with addTarget:action:.

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 6, you can create the unwind segue and perform that. If you're supporting iOS 5, you'll want to write your own gesture handler that calls the appropriate `popViewControllerAnimated` or `dismissViewControllerAnimated` when going backwards.

Comment: Obviously, though, if using containment, you would call your parent controller's "change child routine", or you could put it in a custom segue if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125145/ios-best-practices-for-a-one-way-navigation-controller/14125580#14125580

Comment: I was just about to post that question thanks!