# Swipe gesture between view controllers in storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am looking to add a left and right swipe gesture to change between view controllers, is this possible and is there an easy way to do this in storyboards? Thanks :)

Comment: Edit: see my anser below. I think It's exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Storyboards allow you to set up segues between two view controllers. I would say start by attaching segues between the views, give it an identifier.

Then use something like

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myRightAction)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

to add a swipe recognizer to a view.

Then in the myRightAction method you'd want to do your segue call like

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
```

to go to a view or dismiss it to leave the view.

You can use Navigation View Controllers to have a right and left transition animation. You can also make custom segues.

Answer (score 1):

on Xcode 5 it is simpler, less code needed:

storyboard -> utility panel -> object Library -> drag and drop the Swipe Gesture Recognizer inside your scene

you MUST drag it into the view itself(where the background color appears) so you can see this connection: referencing outlet collections -> view

add the delegate by dragging the delegate's connection pin to the viewController

Show assistant editor -> add an action by ctrl + drag and drop on your delegate class viewController.m

inside that action write

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Comment: I personally prefer this approach since it is more Interface Builder centered and still works in Xcode 7. When you drag the swipe gesture into the view, it should be noted that it will move outside of the view in the document outline, but will still be connected to that view in the "Referencing Outlet Collections" in the Connections Inspector which is critical. It can also be connected manually in the Connections Inspector.

Answer (score -1):

Oops. Posted a comment on accident. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14125580/1126783. You could just use a swipe gesture instead of buttons, and it uses storyboards.